# Get value from the people picker and add it to a list in a person column

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a simple JS form on my SP16 site where I added this standard people picker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
initializePeoplePicker('pickerUAT');
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {
var schema = {};
schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
schema['Width'] = '269px';
this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}
});
```

I am able to get the selected value (as a display name, email, whatever) from the picker like this:

```
function getEmailFromPeoplePicker(title) {
var ppDiv = $("div[title='" + title + "']")[0];
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.pickerUAT_TopSpan;
var userList = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
var userInfo = userList[0];
var addThisUser;
if(userInfo != null)
{
addThisUser = userInfo.Key;
}
return addThisUser;
}
```

And I have a list to which I can add other values taken from other form fields, usually through document.getElementById("XXX").value and this piece of code:

```
function addSubUser(addThisValue)  {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteurl);  
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
var valueToAdd = addThisValue; 
var list = clientContext.get_web()  
.get_lists()  
.getByTitle("UAT");   
this.oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  
oListItem.set_item('userUAT', valueToAdd);  
oListItem.update();  
clientContext.load(oListItem);  
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  
}
```

However, this code doesn't work for the value taken from the people picker. Console.log(typeof addThisUser) tells me the value I get from the picker is just a string, do I assume correctly that I cannot simply add a string to a person/group column? In any event, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You may try to update the filed using two different methods

- as lookup giving ID of user

```
    var LookupSingle = new SP.FieldLookupValue();  
    LookupSingle.set_lookupId(2);  // UserId
    oListItem.set_item('SomeLookupColumn', LookupSingle);
```

- as Single User Field

```
    var singleUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('name surname');  
    oListItem.set_item('SomeSingleUserColumn', singleUser);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used this line with Key and it did the trick: `var singleUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('name surname');`

Answer (score 0):

Sample test script in my local SharePoint 2016(multiple user field).

```
CustomPeoplePicker:
    <div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="SaveItem()" type="button" value="button" />
    <script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
    <script src="_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
        })

        function sharePointReady() {
            context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            web = context.get_web();
            var schema = {};
            schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
            schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
            schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
            schema['Width'] = '280px';

            this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper('peoplePickerDiv', null, schema);
        }

        function SaveItem() {
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");
            var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);
            var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            // Get user keys.
            var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
            var finalusers = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var arryuser = users[i];
                finalusers.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(arryuser.Key));
            }
            listItem.set_item("Title", "Title");
            listItem.set_item("Requestor", finalusers);
            listItem.update();
            ctx.load(listItem);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
                    console.log(listItem);
                }),
                Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                    alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
                })
            );
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, I will use it with my multiple users solution.